# Using Uploadify and having permission problems

Tags: php, html, permissions, uploadify

I'm using uploadify to upload images to a server and their file names to a database, and then using wordpress to dynamically generate pages that will use these photos.  So far, what I have works sometimes, then other times it doesn't work.

I want uploadify to check to see if the file name already exists (I will be having several hundred different users uploading images) and if the file name matches, I have uploadify return an error asking the user to rename the file.  Once a file is successfully uploaded.  I have the uploadify button removed, and return the file's name to a hidden field which will be submitted to my database.

I then use this filename drawn from the database to tell WP where to look for the files.

However, I sometimes get a successful view of the file on the pages created, then sometimes it comes back and tells me that access to the file is forbidden.  I've read up and found several cases of permission issues with uploadify, but nothing I've found and tried has been successful. I've tried adding a chmod command to the uploadify.php, that didn't work.  I've tried changing the permissions on the folder on the server, that did nothing to future uploaded files.  I have no clue what's going wrong to even know where to begin to remedy the problem.  The following is my HTML (just an excerpt containing the relevant uploadify content as the full HTML page is quite large), and my uploadify.php files (there are 2 because I have different parameter checks on each.

Uploadify scripts from the header (both of them):

```
$(function() {
    $('#photo_upload').uploadify({
        'buttonText' : 'Select File',
        'multi'    : false,
        'method'   : 'post',
        'fileSizeLimit' : '100KB',
        'height'   : 20,
        'swf'      : 'uploadify-v3/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify-v3/uploadify.php',
        'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                                           $('#photo_upload').uploadify('settings','formData',{'upName' : $('#usersName').val()});
                                         },
        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data) {
                            if(data == 'failed'){
                                alert('The file you attempted to upload failed.  Please check that the file meets all requirements, then try again. Thank you.');
                            } else if(data == 'FileNameExists'){
                                alert('An image with the same file name already exists.  Please rename the file to a different name, then try again. Thank you.');
                            } else{
                            $("#photo_upload").remove();
                            var starting = data.indexOf("upload-images");
                            var savedAs = data.substring(starting+14 , data.indexOf(".jpg"))+".jpg";
                            document.form.photo.value = savedAs;
                            }
                        }
        // Your options here
    });
    $('#logo_upload').uploadify({
        'buttonText' : 'Select File',
        'multi'    : false,
        'method'   : 'post',
        'fileSizeLimit' : '100KB',
        'height'   : 20,
        'swf'      : 'uploadify-v3/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify-v3/uploadify2.php',
        'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                                           $('#logo_upload').uploadify('settings','formData',{'upName' : $('#usersName').val()});
                                         },
        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data) {
                            if(data == 'failed'){
                                alert('The file you attempted to upload failed.  Please check that the file meets all requirements, then try again. Thank you.');
                            } else if(data == 'FileNameExists'){
                                alert('An image with the same file name already exists.  Please rename the file to a different name, then try again. Thank you.');
                            } else{
                            $("#logo_upload").remove();
                            var starting = data.indexOf("upload-images");
                            var savedAs = data.substring(starting+14 , data.indexOf(".jpg"))+".jpg";
                            document.form.logo.value = savedAs;
                            }
                        }
        // Your options here
    });
});
```

HTML (this is just the relevant HTML for the uploadify buttons and fields):

```
<span class="Form-Header">Upload Images</span>&nbsp;
    <br />
    <div id="Form-wrapper">
        <div id="Form-wrapper-left">
          Your Photograph:<br />
        </div>
        <div id="Form-wrapper-right">
          <input name="photo" type="hidden" id="photo" value="NULL"/>
          <input type="file" name="photo_upload" id="photo_upload" />

          (Image Dimensions: 300w x 420h, JPEG) (100kb Size Limit)
        </div>
        <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div id="Form-wrapper">
        <div id="Form-wrapper-left">
          Your Logo:<br />
        </div>
        <div id="Form-wrapper-right">
          <input name="logo" type="hidden" id="logo" value="NULL"/>
          <input type="file" name="logo_upload" id="logo_upload" />
          (Image Dimensions: 450w x 65h, JPEG) (100kb Size Limit)
        </div>
        <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Form-wrapper">
      <div id="Form-Footer"><strong>Next: </strong> Go <a href="#top">to the top of the page</a> and click on &quot;Profile Information&quot; to continue.<br />
        </div>
        <div id="clear" style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
```

And last, but not least, here are my PHP pages for uploadify1 and uploadify2 (I'm only showing one because they are both the same with the exception of the size requirements):

```
<?php
// Define a destination
$targetFolder = '/Eye-Doctors/upload-images'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

    $size = getimagesize($tempFile);
    if($size[0] <= 300 && $size[1] <= 420){

          $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
          $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

          // Validate the file type
          $fileTypes = array('jpg'); // File extensions
          $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

          if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {

                       $exists = 0;
                        if( file_exists($targetFile) ) {
                                $exists = 1;
                                echo 'FileNameExists';



                        }
              if($exists == 0){
                move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
                echo $targetFile;
              }

          } else {
              echo 'failed';
          }

    } else{
        echo 'failed';
        }
}
?>
```

I really hope that this is enough information to get some help.  I have tried looking everywhere for a solution and still cannot find one.  If there is anything more I can provide to help, please let me know.